# Incomplete end of table created by tabular

Tags: tables

I am using `tabular` to create a table for me. But with the following code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.6cm} | m{5cm} | m{11cm}|} 
  \hline
  \\[-1em]
 1& Name of the applicant: &MR. TANMOY PATI\\
 \\[-1em]
  \hline
\\[-1em]
2&i. Date of birth: & 22/12/2000\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The end of the table are not getting complete.
[image]

How to get rid of these?

Comment: You're missing a final `\hline` after the second row. That's why it's not drawing the bottom of the table.

Comment: What's with the `\\[-1em]` directives?

Comment: ```\\[-1em]``` this makes the  the rwo a bit wider. I think this is creating the problem. Is there any way to make the row wider?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables

Comment: With "wider" I suspect you mean higher... Use `\usepackage{array}\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` in the preamble, change the 1pt to your liking. And remove the `[-1em]`.

Comment: You do not make the row higher with `\\[-1em]`. What you make is add a extra row where you  with  a height shortened by 1 em. This is not only conceptually wrong. You can also see that this have consequences in broken vertical lines because you also omit the cells delimiters of these empty rows. See the package `booktabs` to avoid horizontal lines too close to text (and also the  issues with the vertical lines).